# TFS Continous build custom Drop folder template

Tags: tfs

I am trying to implement continous build process, if i look at the XAML in the sequence Drop Folder I want to specify a custom template

that is I do not want all the files to be dropped in one folder,
I have to create a folder structure like Folder1, Folder2, inside root folder.

**Based on file extension files have to be dropped to particular foldder**

any point how to achieve this,

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy modifying the TFS build templates then Torbjörn's answer is definatly the way to go. Customising the build template will give you complete control of the output. However this can be overkill, especially if you're not familiar with WF and the internals of Team Build. An alternative is to write some msbuild which will run as part fo the build.

To do this create a file called "DropTidy.proj" and edit the file so that it looks something like this

```
<Project DefaultTargets="CopySQLReleaseFiles" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">

  <Target Name="CopySQLReleaseFiles">

    <ItemGroup>
      <SqlBuildOutput Include="$(OutDir)\*.sql" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SqlBuildOutput)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\SQL" />

  </Target>

</Project>
```

The example above will copy all files with an extensions of "sql" in to a folder called "SQL". $(OutDir) is the working folder used by team build that relelates to the "Binaries" folder in the build workspace on your build agent

Check the file in to TFS and then add it to your "Items to Build" list in the Team Build Definition. Make sure that it's the last "Solution" in the list so that it runs after the other solutions in your build. Also make sure that the folder you checked the proj file in to is part of your builds workspace.

Run your build and you should see a new folder called SQL in your drop location.

Comment: thanks, but my application is of DotnetNuke, I have lot of folders like App_LocalResources,DesktopModules, like DotnetNuke\DesktopModules\Module1,module2, each files should be copied to particular location, I have to create drop folder DotNetNuke which contain all this files,  In Xaml drop foler event can i create a code activity, i am not sure how to create this, can you point me to some references

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default build process template (or a derivative of), the actions for copying to DropFolder are inside `Finally` block of `Try Compile, Test and Associate Changesets and Work Items`. You will have to replace that single `Copy to Drop Location` action with your custom sequence. The `FindMatchingFiles` can be used to select a set of files based on a search criterium.

One problem will arise when trying to copy single items; TFS build activities does not have an action for that; only for `CopyDirectory`. You can set up a `InvokeProcess`, alternatively add `Community TFS Build Extensions` from where you'll get `Robocopy` and `Powershell` actions to support such tasks.

If you're using the basic DefaultTemplate, I'd strongly advise you to make your changes in a copy of it and use that for your builds.